# Order by x then order by y column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider a table like

```
   debit    credit  code
-----------------------------
    0       10      5
    5       0       3
    0       11      2
    0       15      1
    7       0       6
    6       0       2
    5       0       1
```

I need to generate a result set like this that debit come first and then ordered by code column:

```
debit   credit  code
----------------------------
5       0       1
6       0       2
5       0       3
7       0       6
0       15      1
0       11      2
0       10      5
```

Comment: Duplicate of [SQL multiple column ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051162/sql-multiple-column-ordering)

Comment: Thanks, but this is not my problem solution, because I need to come debit (greater than zero) come first, then order it by debit and code

Comment: ok, please update your question to state that or be more clear for future readers benefit. Thanks!

Comment: @ElhamAzadfar check the answer I think cte should resolve your issue

Comment: @ElhamAzadfar did it solved your query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this.

```
DECLARE  @MyTable TABLE(debit INT, credit INT,  code INT)

INSERT INTO @MyTable VALUES 
(0, 10, 5),
(5, 0 , 3),
(0, 11, 2),
(0, 15, 1),
(7, 0 , 6),
(6, 0 , 2),
(5, 0 , 1)

SELECT * FROM 
    @MyTable 
ORDER BY 
    (CASE WHEN debit > 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) ,
    code , 
    debit
```

Result:

```
debit       credit      code
----------- ----------- -----------
5           0           1
6           0           2
5           0           3
7           0           6
0           15          1
0           11          2
0           10          5
```

Comment: I think the result from the query won't give the result what OP is asking, in the first column order how come you get the  5,6,5 as it depends on 3rd column value

Comment: Hi Does my solution is helpful?

Comment: @Rams first order just for separate debit >0 rows.

Comment: No i was asking about my answer

Comment: Worked like a charm for me, would you please see this question too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47968160/group-by-then-sort-sql-server

Answer (score 3):

Please use below one in `order by clause` you will get the output that you are looking for

```
  order by cast(cast(code as varchar(50)) 
                              + cast(debit as varchar(2)+ cast(credit as varchar(2) as int)
```

Comment: So `code` `5`, `debit` `11`, `credit` `2` would sort as equal to `5`, `1`, `12`. That doesn't sound right.

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH Props AS
(
SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c,cc) AS RowNumber
FROM Location

)
select * from Props order by d desc,RowNumber
```

Try the above code

[WOrking fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5dacb/5)

Comment: I tried it with the original data and it is not giving the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Use this select to help you:

```
SELECT debit, code, credit  
FROM table a
WHERE debit > 0
or debit = 0
order by debit  code, credit desc
```

or

```
SELECT debit, code, credit  
FROM table a
WHERE debit > 0
or debit = 0
group by debit, code, credit
order by debit  code, credit desc
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I need to debit(with number) come first and then ordered by code column, in this query credit is first

Comment: Thanks again, it's thrown this exception Column 'code' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: I do that but , I want to see all Debit with number greater than zero first

Comment: check now to see if it helps